# matplotlib: make legend keys square

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am working with matplotlib and would like to change the keys in my legends to be squares instead of rectangles when I make, for example, bar plots. Is there a way to specify this?

What I have now:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your own legend keys.

The bar plot in my answer is created using the [matplotlib barchart demo](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html). (I have removed the error bars). The [matplotlib legend guide](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#implementing-a-custom-legend-handler) explains how to define a class to replace legend keys with ellipses. I have modified that class to use squares (by using [rectangle patches](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Rectangle)).

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerPatch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

# Define square (rectangular) patches
# that can be used as legend keys
# (this code is based on the legend guide example)

class HandlerSquare(HandlerPatch):
    def create_artists(self, legend, orig_handle,
                       xdescent, ydescent, width, height, fontsize, trans):
        center = xdescent + 0.5 * (width - height), ydescent
        p = mpatches.Rectangle(xy=center, width=height,
                               height=height, angle=0.0)
        self.update_prop(p, orig_handle, legend)
        p.set_transform(trans)
        return [p]      

# this example is the matplotlib barchart example:

N = 5
menMeans = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27)

ind = np.arange(N)  # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.35       # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, menMeans, width, color='r')

womenMeans = (25, 32, 34, 20, 25)
rects2 = ax.bar(ind+width, womenMeans, width, color='y')

# add some text for labels, title and axes ticks
ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
ax.set_title('Scores by group and gender')
ax.set_xticks(ind+width)
ax.set_xticklabels( ('G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5') )

# append the new patches to the legend-call:

ax.legend( (rects1[0], rects2[0]), ('Men', 'Women'), 
           handler_map={rects1[0]: HandlerSquare(), rects2[0]: HandlerSquare()})

plt.show()
```

Having defined the `class HandlerSquare`, one can now apply this to each legend entry as a third argument to the `ax.legend` call. Note the syntax:

```
handler_map={rects1[0]: HandlerSquare(), rects2[0]: HandlerSquare()}
```

The `handler_map` has to be a dictionary.

This will give you this plot:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

If you want a very quick and dirty solution to get an approximate square (that may require some fine-tuning depending on your plot), you can adjust the  `handlelength` kwarg in the legend call. Following Schorsch's solution (i.e. once you have a list of rectangular legend artists and corresponding labels):

```
ax.legend((rects1[0], rects2[0]), ('Men', 'Women'), handlelength=0.7)
```

See [matplotlib `legend()` docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.legend) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Modifying `handlelength` globally affects the width of other markers in the legend. That solution will therefore be incompatible with, e.g. a combination of point and line patches. Instead, you can just add a square point marker to the legend using `Line2D`. You just have to set its associated line to zero-width:

```
rect1 = mlines.Line2D([], [], marker="s", markersize=30, linewidth=0, color="r")
rect2 = mlines.Line2D([], [], marker="s", markersize=30, linewidth=0, color="y")
ax.legend((rect1, rect2), ('Men', 'Women'))
```