# Create a matplotlib mpatches with a rectangle bi-colored for figure legend

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

i need to create a patch for a legend in a matplotlib figure whose handlebox is a a rectangle with two color. something like this, that i have made with paint coping, cutting and coloring: [image]

Can you tell me how and where to start?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would of course start at the [matplotlib legend guide](https://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html); more specifically at the section about [implementing a custom handler](https://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#implementing-a-custom-legend-handler).

Reading some other questions on customizing the legend, like

- [Completely custom legend in Matplotlib, Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28739608/completely-custom-legend-in-matplotlib-python)
- [using mpatches.Patch for a custom legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44098362/using-mpatches-patch-for-a-custom-legend)
- [Insert image in matplotlib legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26029592/insert-image-in-matplotlib-legend)
- [Replace Matplotlib legend's labels with image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42155119/replace-matplotlib-legends-labels-with-image)
- [How to show shapefile label in python basemap legend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42639981/how-to-show-shapefile-label-in-python-basemap-legend)

may also help.

Here you want to put two rectangles in the legend. So inside a custom `Handler` class, you can create those and add them to the `handlebox`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Handler(object):
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color=color
    def legend_artist(self, legend, orig_handle, fontsize, handlebox):
        x0, y0 = handlebox.xdescent, handlebox.ydescent
        width, height = handlebox.width, handlebox.height
        patch = plt.Rectangle([x0, y0], width, height, facecolor='blue',
                                   edgecolor='k', transform=handlebox.get_transform())
        patch2 = plt.Rectangle([x0+width/2., y0], width/2., height, facecolor=self.color,
                                   edgecolor='k', transform=handlebox.get_transform())
        handlebox.add_artist(patch)
        handlebox.add_artist(patch2)
        return patch


plt.gca()

handles = [plt.Rectangle((0,0),1,1) for i  in range(4)]
colors = ["limegreen", "red", "gold", "blue"]
hmap = dict(zip(handles, [Handler(color) for color in colors] ))

plt.legend(handles=handles, labels=colors, handler_map=hmap)

plt.show()
```

[image: two rectangles in custom legend]