# Is it possible to have two different marker styles for a label in a Matplotlib legend?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to customise a Matplotlib legend so that one of the labels is represented by two markers with different styles (e.g. ☆/▽ My label). I have seen that you can [customise legend markers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27826064/1862861) by making a patch for the marker, but can you create and use two patches (and at a push maybe add a "/" as a separator)? An option may also be to create a LaTeX string for the marker using TikZ, but that seems like overkill.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It seems hard to read.

Comment: In my case the star and triangle represent different parameters, so I still have labels for them individually. However, there is a sub-class of both parameters that corresponds to a particular situation, so I want to show when this situation is the case for both parameters using differently coloured stars and triangles, but with both labelled for the particular situation. Trying to do what I asked probably is more tricky than required (I could just caption my figure with the required information), but I thought it worth asking in case someone else had done it.

Comment: I'd use something *else* for the sub-class, like putting a circle around those markers (overplot them with a big, hollow circle, put the circle in the legend).

Comment: Or put a square of the special-case color in the legend, though people do probably read that as "square marker".

Comment: I've done this before by having colours for attribute 1 and shapes for attribute two, and then building the legend manually like a lookup table. If you want the graph to be publishable in a non colour journal though, then you'd have to use non colour options (i.e. line thickness/dashtype/marker shapes).

Comment: @cphlewis - thanks, I think putting a circle around the sub-class markers will probably be the route I take

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do it would be to define custom markers using mathtext (see [matplotlib documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html)) and define the legend handle of the subclass with a proxy:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close('all')

# Generate some data :

x1 = np.arange(1, 20)
y1 = np.log(x1) + np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=len(x1))/5

x2 = np.arange(1, 20)
y2 = np.log(x2) + np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=len(x2))/5

# Plot data :

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

h1, = ax.plot(x1[x1>5], y1[x1>5], ls='none', marker=r'$\star$',
              ms=12, mec='0.15', mfc='0.15', mew=1, alpha=0.5)

h2, = ax.plot(x2[x2>5], y2[x2>5], ls='none', marker=r'$\blacktriangledown$',
              ms=12, mec='0.15', mfc='0.15', mew=1, alpha=0.5)

ax.plot(x1[x1<=5], y1[x1<=5], ls='none', marker=r'$\star$',
        ms=12, mec='red', mfc='red', mew=1, alpha=0.5)

ax.plot(x2[x2<=5], y2[x2<=5], ls='none', marker=r'$\blacktriangledown$',
        ms=12, mec='red', mfc='red', mew=1, alpha=0.5)

# Create a proxy for the subclass :

h3, = ax.plot([], ls='none', marker=r'$\star/\blacktriangledown$',
              ms=24, mec='red', mfc='red', mew=1, alpha=0.5)


# Generate legend :

handles = [h1, h2, h3]
labels = ['dataset1', 'dataset2', 'transient state']
ax.legend(handles, labels, loc=4, ncol=1, numpoints=1, frameon=False)

# Save and show the figure :

fig.savefig('custom_legend_markers.png')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I asked for in the question, so I'll mark this as the accepted answer. However, ideally I'd like control over the marker face colour and transparency, which I don't think you can do with mathtext (well [maybe using TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11390/drawing-stars-similar-with-tikz)), so being able to do it with Matplotlib patches would be nice.

Comment: @MattPitkin You can to some extent. You have to chose latex markers that are filled, like `\blacktriangledown` instead of `\triangledown`. I updated my answer to take into account your comment.

Comment: Great, that did the trick (I had tried that earlier, but it hadn't worked when using `text.usetex = True`).